# Kendo Ui trasport update get data from save event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Refer to the image below, I create a popup template together with 2 table inside. So when I click on submit button it will fetch all records in red and also yellow box. For now it only fetch records in red only.

When submit button trigger, `save` event will be called and `transport > update` will be read as well. so in my `save` event I create a code that will fetch all the records inside the yellow grid. Now my concern how to merge the record that I fetch in `save` event together along with the record in `transport > update`?

[image]

kendo dataSource `transport > update`

```js
update: {
  url:  "./getRecipe.php",
  type: "POST",
  data :function() {
          return { 
            method: "editRecipe",
            this_propertyID : $('#thisPropertyID').val(),
            // get together with all items value.
          }
  },                         
},
```

on `save` event

```js
function onSave(e){
  console.log('submit button trigger');

    var gridDataArray = $('#itemGrid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.data();
    var items = [];
    for ( var i=0; i < gridDataArray.length; i++ ) {    
        items.push({
          ["itemID_" + i]: gridDataArray[i]['itemID'],
          ["itemQty_" + i]: gridDataArray[i]['itemQuantity'],
          ["itemPrice_" + i]: gridDataArray[i]['itemPrice']
        })               
    };
    console.log(items);
    //I need to store this object and when submit submit button trigger it  will call from transport update.

}
```

***Update***

I try to insert the code in `save` event into `transport > update` and merge the `object`

```js
  update: {
  url:  "./getRecipe.php",
  type: "POST",
  data :function() {

    var gridDataArray = $('#itemGrid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.data();
    var items = [];
    for ( var i=0; i < gridDataArray.length; i++ ) {    
      items.push({
      ["itemID_" + i]: gridDataArray[i]['itemID'],
      ["itemQty_" + i]: gridDataArray[i]['itemQuantity'],
      ["itemPrice_" + i]: gridDataArray[i]['itemPrice']
      })                 
    };
    console.log(items);

    var data = { 
      method: "editRecipe",
      this_propertyID : $('#thisPropertyID').val(),
    };

    var x = {... data, ... items};
    return x;
  },                         
},
```

But the output like this? How to remove those `0[itemID_0]: LA1` so it can become `itemID_0: LA1` only?

[image]

Comment: try `items.push({
      "itemID_" + i: gridDataArray[i]['itemID'],
      "itemQty_" + i: gridDataArray[i]['itemQuantity'],
      "itemPrice_" + i: gridDataArray[i]['itemPrice']
      })   `